# Best practice with android fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

at the moment I'm calling and building fragments like this:

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_list) == null) {
     list = new MyListFragment();
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_list, list).commit();
}
```

But I wonder if this is so called best practice, because this seems to me to be much boilerplate code. Are there better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XML layouts and Fragment classes. Here I create a layout with 2 fragments. The class inflates the layout `fragment_actionbarcompat.xml` (that code isn't shown here but it's a basic layout file). And I create a layout file for the activity that houses the 2 fragments.

The ActionBarCompatFragment class overrides the onCreateView method to inflate it's layout. That gets injected into the fragment tag layoutwise.

In your case normally you don't just add in a plain `ListFragment`, you extend `ListFragment` and add your custom code into it. It's a way of better supporting fancy patterns like Model-View-Controller. Fragments are meant to be isolated compartments so you can reuse them between activities if you'd like. In most cases your class will hold the logic to load the data that the fragment needs.

**ActionBarCompatFragment.java**

```
@Override
public final View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup root, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final int layoutId = R.layout.fragment_actionbarcompat;
    return inflater.inflate(layoutId, root, false);
}
```

**File: activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ActionBarCompatFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ActionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        class="com.packagename.app.ActionBarCompatFragment" >

        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/fragment_actionbarcompat -->
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ComposerFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ActionBarCompatFragment"
        class="com.packagename.app.ComposerFragment" >

        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/fragment_composer -->
    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes that's what I have.
The code above shows my Activity `onCreate()` which instantiates the `MyListFragment extend ListFragment`.
But I wondered if there are better ways to "call" a fragment apart from my code posted above (check null, create new myfragment, begin, commit etc).

Comment: Using the XML way the Android system will instantiate the fragment for you. It basically reads the XML behind the scenes and uses reflection to do this. You can then get a handle to the fragment itself by calling Activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.*); (remove Activity.getFragmentManager() if not using support package)

Comment: Oh indeed it works without initialisating the fragments myself. Just the findFragement as you mentioned is enough. Thanks a lot, that make my code much better now.